# Using SQLConnection object in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to use the SQLConnection object as I would from vb, for example.  I'd like to do this:

e.g.

```
$conn = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder
$conn.DataSource = 'myserver'
```

but this fails:

```
Keyword not supported: 'DataSource'.
At line:1 char:4
+ $conn. <<<< DataSource = 'myserver'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

even though:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell> $conn|Get-Member *sour*


   TypeName: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder

Name       MemberType Definition
----       ---------- ----------
DataSource Property   System.String DataSource {get;set;}
```

My Powershell version:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.3634
BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18111
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

What is causing the error message?

Specifically, this works:

```
$conn.database = 'mydb'
```

(and sets the property 'InitialCatalog')

and this fails

```
$conn.initialcatalog = 'mydb'
```

even though:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell> $conn|Get-Member initialcatalog 


TypeName: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder 

Name MemberType Definition 
---- ---------- ---------- 
InitialCatalog Property System.String InitialCatalog {get;set;}
```

What I'm confused about is why I can set the "database" property even though it's not in the member list, but I cannot set the properties in the member list, even though PS says that they are set-able.

Comment: What about just using  $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection and give it a connection string?

Comment: I'd rather build it up property by property.  But really I what I want to know is, why it doesn't work by setting the exposed properties but *does* work by setting hidden properties.

Answer (score 5):

The "Keyword" is "Data Source" so you have to set `$ConnString."Data Source" = 'myserver'`

Edit: Adding explanation

Step 1: SqlConnectionStringBuilder derives from DbConnectionStringBuilder which implements the IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable, and ICustomTypeDescriptor interfaces.

Step 2: SqlConnectionStringBuilder::InitialCatalog internally just sets SqlConnectionStringBuilder::Item['Initial Catalog'].

Step 3: When we combine the previous statements, we get the following result:

```
PS> $sc = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
PS> $sc.InitialCatalog.Equals($sc.Item('Initial Catalog'))
True

PS> $sc.InitialCatalog.Equals($sc.Item('Database'))
True

# And just for completeness
PS> $sc.InitialCatalog.Equals($sc.Item('Server'))
False
```

So, when you execute this:

```
$Conn.InitialCatalog = "mydb'
```

It gets translated to:

```
$Conn.Item['Initial Catalog'] = "mydb"
```

To see the available properties to use in this manner, run this command:

```
$Conn.Keys
```

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. It explains exactly the problem, cause and workaround. I have the same problem and the workaround works for me. If you think it's an unhelpful answer, please add something useful or at least an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that both .psbase and -Property give you access to the connection string properties by name, as in

```
$conn = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder
$conn.psbase.DataSource= 'yourDataSource'
```

or

```
$conn = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder -Property @{DataSource='ursrc'}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! - should be accepted IMO

Answer (score 0):

Still don't have a *reason* why this fails, but a different way to get this to work is to call the setters directly rather than trying to set the value of the properties:

```
$conn.set_InitialCatalog("mydb")
```

should behave as you expect.